# Checking if an element in first list of strings occurs in second list of strings

Tags: python, list, loops

I apologise if there are dupes! I've tried looking for similar questions but no luck :(
Let's say my code is like the following:

```
buckets = []
A = ["apple", "pear", "orange"]
B = ["pear"]

for a in A:
    if a in B:
        buckets.append(A[a])
```

so since pear from A occurs in B, I'd like to append "pear" to my list to show that "pear" is in list A and has occurred in list B. However I'm getting an error saying

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

The question seems really trivial but I can't seem to find the bug. Any help would be appreciated!

EDIT : it was such a small fix! So sorry for such a redundant-looking question. Thanks for answering!

Comment: When you test `if a in B:`, what are you expecting the value of `a` to be? If the test succeeds, what do you want to put into the `buckets`? What is the relationship between that value, and the `a` value? "The question seems really trivial but I can't seem to find the bug" Well, did you *read* the error message? Do you understand what it means? Do you understand how it relates to the line of code it's complaining about? For example, in `buckets.append(A[a])`, what do you think is the `list` it's talking about? What do you think is the `index` it's talking about?

Comment: Also, what happened when you tried copying and pasting the message, `TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str`, into a search engine? When I do that, I get many useful results.

Answer (score 2):

Here `A[a]` you are trying to get element using the element itself. `for a in A` produces items, not indexes.

The fix is simple:

```
buckets.append(a)
```

And actually this could have been achieved easier:

```
buckets = list(set(A).intersection(B))
```

Comment: `set(A + B)` will give you the union of A and B. That does not seem to be what the OP is asking for.

Comment: @khelwood agreed. Fixed the answer.

Comment: omg thank you so much everyone LOL how did i not SEE that :( thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You iterate through words of the list, not through indexes. Meaning you're indexing a list type with a string, which is not as list-type works. A quick fix would be:

```
for a in A:
    if a in B:
        buckets.append(a)
```

Comment: omg thank you so much everyone LOL how did i not SEE that :( thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You are on the right track. Just your append statement is incorrect. Do this

```
buckets = []
A = ["apple", "pear", "orange"]
B = ["pear"]

for a in A:
    if a in B:
        buckets.append(a)
```

A pythonic way is using list comprehension:

```
buckets =[i for i in A if i in B]
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this should work fine

```
buckets = []
A = ["apple", "pear", "orange"]
B = ["pear"]

for a in A:
    if a in B:
        buckets.append(a)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    buckets = []
    A = ["apple", "pear", "orange"]
    B = ["pear"]

    for a in A:
        if a in B:
            buckets.append(a)
```